# I want to change the size of a "restored" window. How do I go about doing that? 

Tags: windows, window-manager

I want to change the size of a "restored" window. is there a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Re-size it, then hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd>
 key down while closing it. Re-open it to test.

Comment: After posting this answer, it is also worth mentioning that some are set at a fixed size by the programmer, and I hate when they do that. If that does not do it, please be more specfic as to OS, and what kind of window.

Comment: I second.  Most programs are well behaved. . . But not all programmers are created equal.

Comment: the solution doesn't seem to work on Chrome..

Comment: Are you primarily concerned with Chrome, or just in general?